# Can Adobe Ilustrator export to Sketch?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, interface-design, sketch-app

Can Adobe Ilustrator export to Sketch file?

If not, is there any plugin that can be used?

Comment: https://www.sketchapp.com/support/documentation/13-other/1-importing.html

Comment: Since Sketch can't really import AI files, you may want to export your AI file as an SVG or PDF and then import that into Sketch, that would give you the best compatibility.

Answer (score 2):

Save your .ai as .svg file
And open the svg inside Sketch app.
It work for simple vectors files.

Comment: For more complex vector files I'd recommend using https://xd2sketch.com/converter/ai-to-sketch

Answer (score 0):

You can also just copy and paste. Most things import fine that way, though there might be problems with effects or illustrator-specific features.